# Alternate way to pivot the data without using SUM or MAX?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I need to transpose a data but when I do so using PIVOT SUM / MAX is aggregating the value. How to get the data as without aggregating?

Need a help on this SQL query to get output.

**Data in table:**

```
Code ColVal
A     1
A     2
A     3
B     1
B     2
B     3
B     4
C     1
C     2
```

**Expected output:**

```
A    B   C
1    1   1
2    2   2
3    3   NULL
NULL 4   NULL
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM (
SELECT Code,ColA
FROM Table) TBL
PIVOT (SUM(ColA) FOR Code IN (A,B,C)) AS pvt
```

Comment: You *have* to use an aggregate function. Pivoting, in SQL, is a form of aggregation.

Comment: Yes looking for an alternate way.

Comment: Don't use SQL; that's your alternative. Pivoting is best done in the application layer anyway.

Comment: Also you [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76706041/2029983) this question and didn't even bother to address the problem of the images...

Comment: Any problem in images?

Comment: See the question you deleted minutes ago; I posted a comment there.

Comment:  Please don't expect us to work with [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, it cannot be consumed, used or searched on; please use *text* for text.

Comment: What if one column looks like: 1, NULL, 3, NULL. should the pivot be 1, 3, NULL, NULL, or 1, NULL, 3 , NULL

Comment: It can be 1, NULL, 3, NULL.

Comment: Tables don't have any ordering so there is no such thing as a column being ordered `1, NULL, 3, NULL`  or `1, 3, NULL, NULL` - if you mean *relative to another column* (e.g. this is the ordering you see when you order by `id`) then use that other column in the row numbering instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PIVOT` requires an aggregate.

To get your desired results you need to add a synthetic column for the implicit `GROUP BY`. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/s4SEO4Ym).

There will only be one row per `RN, Code` combination so the `MAX` just aggregates that single value

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM (
SELECT Code, /* Spreading column */
       ColVal, /* value column */ 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY ColVal) AS RN /* grouping column */ 
FROM YourTable) TBL
PIVOT (MAX(ColVal) FOR Code IN (A,B,C)) AS pvt
```

Comment: Thank you! grouping column part saved my time.